# DataBinding Generic Function

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

I'm currently developing a android application using data binding and mvvm.

I tried to bind a generic function to my recyclerView but can't compile

Layout:

```
 <data>
<import type="android.view.View" />
    <import type="com.app.Models.UserRole" />

    <variable
        name="usersViewModel"
        type="com.app.UI.Users.UsersViewModel" />
</data>

-- ...
-- ...
-- ...
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewUsers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_user"
                android:background="@color/colorBackground"
                app:adapter="@{&lt;UserRole&gt;usersViewModel.usersRoleList}" />
```

BindingAdapter class:

```
@BindingAdapter("adapter")
fun <T : BaseModel> addItems(recyclerView: RecyclerView, mutableList: MutableList<T>) {
    val adapter = MasterAdapter<T>(arrayListOf(), { _, _ -> })
    adapter.pushItems(mutableList)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.context)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
```

MasterAdapter class:

```
class MasterAdapter<T : BaseModel>(var items: MutableList<T>, private val listener: (T, Int) -> Unit)
```

BaseModel interface:

```
interface BaseModel {
    @LayoutRes fun layoutId(): Int
}
```

My question is how pass the model to my generic function using databinding in the layout?